# How could I display a *specific* user's information through an instance variable in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is the code I'm currently using:

**profile_controller.rb:**

```
@user = User.first :conditions => [ "lower(username) = ?", params[:id].downcase ]
```

**show.html.haml:**

```
.footer #{@user.bets.count} -# This displays 0, even though I can see that the user has multiple bets associated with his username in the db
```

My users sign in with Twitter and their usernames could be in any case variation (e.g. BOB, bob, BoB, Bob etc.) - and naturally, any information associated with their username should be accordingly displayed regardless of how the users have signed in.

One strange bug I'm running into is that all associated information with the username seems to be lost once a user signs out, and signs back in; however, this happens seemingly at random times. That is, a user can sign out and sign back in several times without issue, but once in a while, seems to lose all associated information in the profile.

Any tips on how I could go about ensuring this isn't the case? Is the controller code I posted correct, or should I be checking for another parameter other than `param[:id]`?

**EDIT: Thanks for the comments, guys. It turns out that I was overwriting the user information if they just sign in with different case variations. I cleaned this up, and it works now.**

Comment: what are you using for authentication? OmniAuth?

Comment: Are you saving the user's information locally?

Comment: Have a look at your log files. You'll see the SQL that was generated for `@user.bets.count`. You can then execute the exact statement (with same ID etc.) on your database to see what causes the zero-result. I can't be a problem of `@user`, because you couldn't call `@user.bets` if `@user` wouldn't be properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking to do something like:

```
@user = User.where(:username => params[:username].downcase).first
```

Comment: This will translate into the same SQL statement as the original query. (Assuming you just forgot to call `lower()` for case-insensitive comparison on `username`. This may not be needed depending on the DBMS and its configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly including the `bets` when retrieving the user:

```
@user = User.includes(:bets).where("lower(username) = ?", params[:id].downcase).first
```

which will automatically retrieve all related bets.

Normally using `@user.bets` it is lazy loaded, but once it is loaded, it just uses the `bets` in memory. To explicitly load all bets again from database, you could also write:

```
@user.bets.reload.count
```